# Problems with jQuery Hide/Show

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a few problems with a hide/show function in jQuery that I can't seem to figure out. I have a if/else statement which is checking against a data attribute in my HTML, it's then hiding/showing the element based on the results of it. I've been able to log the entire function and it's triggering the correct statements when they are supposed to, but the problem I'm having is getting the content to reappear again after it was hidden. It hides properly, but never comes back. Here is the code:

```
  var bar = $("#alert");
      if (!supressed) {
        bar.animate({height:0});
        bar.parent().animate({height:0}, function() {
          $(this).hide()
        });
      }

       if (supressed) {
       console.log("Supressing");
       bar.replaceWith(newBar);
       bar.parent().animate({height: "45px"}, function() {
         $(this).show()
       });
       bar.animate({height: "45px"});
     }
```

The problem is occuring where the `console.log("Supressing");` statement is. It logs it to the console so I know it's working, but for some reason the bar is not appearing at all.

If I do an inspect element I can still see that the parent of `#alert` still has `style="height: 0px; display: none;"` on it.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: you have missed semicolon after `var supressed = true` and `supressed` is always true as per your code. What is `newBar` variable and why `bar.animate({height: "45px"});` after animation?

Comment: What is the value of newBar?

Comment: It would help to see the HTML that goes along with this as well.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar i think that's not important that supressed code will always run since it will replicate his problem, there might be some other logic that actually determines what value is suppresed that is unimportant

Comment: @nnnnnn it refer's to bar's parent as its in an anonymous funciton

Comment: It's part of a much larger function so I shortened it. All #alert is is a div with some text in it. The value of newBar replaces the HTML of #alert which is why I have it hiding the parent. The only problem with the function is that the parent of #alert will not reappear. Everything else works fine.

Comment: Which element do you think the `bar` variable refers to after you do `bar.replaceWith(newBar)`? (Does it work if you add `bar = newBar;` after that line?)

Comment: @nnnnnn It refers to #alert, all I'm having problem with is that its parent div will not show again after I run $(this).show

Comment: I modified the example to avoid confusion.

Comment: My point was that in your original example `bar` refered to the element that was *removed*, so it wouldn't have a parent. That variable doesn't magically update to refer to the new element even if the new element has the same id. Are you sure your simplified code after the edit still doesn't work?

Comment: @nnnnnn I have to agree. The code after James's edit seems straightforward, I bet the problem was related to the original pasted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're using the [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) function (first line after the `else` statement). Then you call bar.parent() after the element has been removed from the DOM.

Maybe you meant to say

```
newBar.parent().animate({height: "45px"}, function() {
  $(this).show()
});
```

Comment: I solved this slightly differently but it essentially used the same logic. Thanks for the help.